# Help understanding and debugging slow boot with systemd network-online.target

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, kde, systemd

I've spent some time on google, but I don't want a quick fix here, I want to understand what is going on. I have a desktop which boots to Windows in 3 seconds, and booted older ubuntu's in under 10, but with Kubuntu 15.10 it takes over 40 seconds to boot, and the KDE login is also very slow.

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain 

graphical.target @9.961s
└─multi-user.target @9.961s
  └─getty.target @9.961s
    └─getty@tty1.service @9.961s
      └─rc-local.service @9.925s +3ms
        └─network-online.target @9.924s
          └─network.target @1.000s
            └─wpa_supplicant.service @1.772s +338ms
              └─basic.target @797ms
                └─sockets.target @797ms
                  └─avahi-daemon.socket @797ms
                    └─sysinit.target @795ms
                      └─networking.service @740ms +54ms
                        └─apparmor.service @416ms +323ms
                          └─local-fs.target @409ms
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @409ms
                              └─systemd-remount-fs.service @401ms +6ms
                                └─system.slice @128ms
                                  └─-.slice @128ms
```

So it's clear that the delay is due to waiting to get online. Many questions here:

1. Why would a desktop version of Ubuntu **block** my boot and log in waiting for a network connection? Can these services not start after I booted? I want to understand why anyone thinks this is reasonable at all. Even for a server, wouldn't it be better to let it boot and then start up services which require network?
2. How can I debug which services are blocking on network? I tried `$ systemctl show network-online.target` and it just shows me that the online target is wanted by `kerneloops.service`. Why would that service need internet to start? Also, this seems like something that would come standard on install. I imagine I can disable that one, but I don't want to spend the next 3 hours disabling and rebooting one by one. Is there a better way to see all of the services which are blocking on `network-online.target`? Can I defer these services to start post-login instead of disabling them?
3. This is the least important to me, but on a desktop with an ethernet connection to a router, why is it taking nearly 10 seconds to get online?

Answer (score 1):

I (partially) solved this, so I wanted to post how in case anyone with similar problems finds this.

**Summary**: I commented out the line `After=network-online.target` in `/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d/debian.conf`. Note that this may break rc.local scripts which depend on network.

Here's how I found it. First, I read some resources [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/what-is-an-init-system/).

From my post above, I knew that `network-online.target` was slow, and from googling I knew that it was the thing that waits to have a network connection. I ran `systemctl list-dependencies network-online.target --before` to determine which services were waiting until after network started, and saw that `rc-local.service` was there. Also, the graphical target (which I think is the thing that brings up the log in screen) depended on `rc-local.service`. I ran `systemctl cat rc-local.service` and saw that Debian had added the `After` dependency on online, some more info [in this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1451797).

I *think* this is safe, as long as you don't have anything in rc.local that needs network, which should be the case for most normal non-server installs.

Now my system "boots" in about 3 seconds, but takes ages to log in after I type my password, so I may have just kicked the bucket down the road, but at least I made progress.

Comment: Update: some upgrade brought this behavior back, along with apt-daily.timer being slow, which has a workaround reported here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service