# Boot time Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, boot-time

I have an HP Laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 installed (dual boot with Windows 10). The system takes over 1m to boot, as you can see from the following:

```
$ systemd-analyze time && systemd-analyze blame
Startup finished in 3.504s (kernel) + 1min 7.512s (userspace) = 1min 11.016s
         24.675s apt-daily.service
         16.924s apt-daily-upgrade.service
         15.427s dev-sda4.device
         11.694s systemd-journald.service
         11.549s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          8.627s systemd-sysctl.service
          6.496s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.204s snapd.service
          3.586s gpu-manager.service
          3.033s systemd-modules-load.service
          2.285s NetworkManager.service
          2.067s udisks2.service
          1.856s thermald.service
          1.633s ModemManager.service
          1.595s accounts-daemon.service
          1.468s apparmor.service
          1.368s lightdm.service
          1.181s iio-sensor-proxy.service
          1.035s systemd-rfkill.service
           986ms grub-common.service
           915ms keyboard-setup.service
           778ms upower.service
           734ms plymouth-start.service
```

**CPU**: `sudo lscpu` (see also `inxi -C`)

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               1995.596
CPU max MHz:           2900,0000
CPU min MHz:           800,0000
BogoMIPS:              3991.19
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

**Graphics HW**: `lspci | grep VGA` (see also `inxi -G`)

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] (rev ff)`
```

So, what can I do to make boot faster (if it’s possible in my case)?

Comment: Try this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: @michele_ub Please [edit] your question and add all details and updates there. Don’t worry about the article length, StackExchange is [pretty benevolent](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17615/what-are-the-limits-for-answer-and-question-lengths).

Comment: @Melebius You mean the question above or my first comment to the first answer ? Then, you want I add CPU and Gpraphics details of my machine removing the link to pastebin?

Comment: @michele_ub Especially the [update in your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999662/boot-time-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1615884_999662), since it’s necessary to distinguish the question from being duplicate to https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service, so it shall be part of the question itself.

Comment: @Melebius Please can you tell me how to add code in a comment?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include all details, including updates. Use the block formatting by pressing the Code icon on toolbar or Ctrl+K.

Comment: @Melebius I preferred to add an answer and delete my first comment. I mean, is more clear.

Comment: It _would_ be better if it didn’t make the question & answer duplicate…

Comment: @Melebius I know, but the solution worked. Most likely you meant was better to add even the "new" output in the question above (and the code to solve) ? If you prefer, I can delete my answer and add all this info in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72229/discussion-between-michele-ub-and-melebius).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [the link recommended](https://askubuntu.com/a/897432/349837) by @fixi7 in the first comment, I found the solution to my issue (it seems to work), that is, do: `sudo systemctl edit apt-daily.timer` and paste the following text into the editor window:

```
# apt-daily timer configuration override
[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=1d
AccuracySec=1h
RandomizedDelaySec=30min
```

Now, the output of `$ systemd-analyze time && systemd-analyze blame`
is:

```
Startup finished in 3.454s (kernel) + 27.151s (userspace) = 30.605s
     15.729s dev-sda4.device
     11.691s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
     10.565s systemd-sysctl.service
      5.548s udisks2.service
      5.384s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.860s snapd.service
      3.605s console-setup.service
      2.556s gpu-manager.service
      2.027s ModemManager.service
      1.996s lightdm.service
      1.982s accounts-daemon.service
      1.817s apparmor.service
      1.660s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.416s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.371s thermald.service
      1.240s keyboard-setup.service
      1.183s systemd-modules-load.service
       979ms apt-daily.service
       924ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       911ms systemd-journald.service
       818ms dev-loop0.device
       734ms irqbalance.service
       606ms avahi-daemon.service
```

Time to boot is considerably reduced.