# Package operation failed E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

When I run software update I get

```
  package operation failed
```

The updates downloaded ok.

The error window disappeared so fast, I could not write down errors.

I ran sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

```
  Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/apt_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

While following the answer below I got:

```
Unpacking apt (1.6.6ubuntu0.1) over (1.6.6) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apt_1.6.6ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
unable to make backup link of './lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer' 
before installing new version: Operation not permitted dpkg-deb: 
error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

Answer (score 1):

Months ago I added the immutable attribute to apt-daily.timer.

For some reason, software updater decided it did not like that.

After removing the attribute, software updater now works. ?

Comment: Next time consider to [disable these timers or mask them](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039155/66509). File-system hacks are dangerous (as you have seen) :)

Comment: I don't see what I did as dangerous per se. I only did it because sometimes my customized apt.daily.timer is overwritten. It is just part of the learning process. I have a script that copies that version on each boot up. I keep a file of most changes I make just in case problems develop. :-)