# Boot stuck at “started daily apt upgrade and clean activities” (18.10)

Tags: boot, apt, 18.10

I have Ubuntu 18.10, and the boot has been stuck there for over half an hour.

I’ve had no problems lately but:

- in the last 2 days I got messages saying that sources could not be updated because there was “no connection” (but I was happily surfing the web)
- yesterday I also got multiple “internal error” messages
  Unfortunately I was focused on a specific activity and didn't pay much attention to messages

Any ideas?

Thank you!!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038923/do-i-really-need-apt-daily-service-and-apt-daily-upgrade-service .

Comment: Thank you! One correction: it’s 18.10 I’m running. Also in my case the boot is completely blocked. After a while I decided to stop it and try anew: as I hit the power button I saw the boot log resuming, than quickly ubuntu’s loading screen, then it was off. I tried turning it on again and it was the same, except I saw no log at all, just black screen and blinking cursor, until I hit the off button.

Comment: Can you boot into Recovery Mode and execute the commands suggested in n0rbert's link?

Comment: I’m afraid apt-daily is not the problem... I can access recovery mode but then fsck can’t run (can’t find etc/default/rcS), dpkg can’t run (“your python installation is broken, repair the symbolic link”)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Answer (score 1):

My bad: root partition was full.
Thanks to everybody who tried to help.

Comment: Hi, too late question but, what was the solution, not being able to boot how did you erase the files? or before that how did you check the file capacity?