# Kernel boot time is very slow on Ubuntu 18.04.4, 1 min+

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 and for some reason my boot time is very slow and it's being caused by my kernel.  Here's the result of `systemd-analyze time`

```bsh
~ ᐅ  systemd-analyze time                                                                                                                                                                  
Startup finished in 1min 17.224s (kernel) + 13.352s (userspace) = 1min 30.576s                                                                                                             
graphical.target reached after 13.347s in userspace
```

So I'm not really sure why this would be the case.

I'm running this kernel version

```
~ ᐅ  uname -r
4.15.0-91-generic
```

Also, my OS is intalled on an SSD drive so it should be fast, and it used to be, some at some point a while ago it got slow.

Any help would really be appreciated.  Let me know if there's any other commands I need to run to and I'll post the results here.

EDIT:

Output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` :

```bsh
~ ᐅ  systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @15.969s
└─multi-user.target @15.969s
  └─docker.service @11.929s +4.040s
    └─network-online.target @11.928s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @4.093s +7.834s
        └─NetworkManager.service @3.272s +817ms
          └─dbus.service @3.068s
            └─basic.target @3.067s
              └─sockets.target @3.067s
                └─docker.socket @3.066s +753us
                  └─sysinit.target @3.063s
                    └─swap.target @3.063s
                      └─dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap @3.058s +5ms
                        └─dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device @3.057s
```

Output of `systemd-analyze blame` :

```bsh
~ ᐅ  systemd-analyze blame
         11.199s apt-daily.service
          7.834s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          4.040s docker.service
          2.772s dev-sdc1.device
          1.606s snapd.service
          1.539s apparmor.service
          1.260s motd-news.service
           989ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
           871ms mysql.service
           865ms phpsessionclean.service
           841ms dev-loop11.device
           841ms dev-loop9.device
           835ms dev-loop10.device
           829ms dev-loop8.device
           817ms NetworkManager.service
           743ms dev-loop0.device
           741ms dev-loop1.device
           741ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           732ms dev-loop2.device
           723ms dev-loop3.device
           691ms ModemManager.service
           676ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           641ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           638ms udisks2.service
           612ms apache2.service
           575ms timidity.service
           570ms dev-loop6.device
           559ms dev-loop7.device
           556ms dev-loop4.device
           542ms dev-loop5.device
           462ms apt-daily-upgrade.service
           412ms networking.service
           410ms snap-slack-22.mount
           409ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount
           406ms snap-core18-1668.mount
           405ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1474.mount
           405ms snap-core-8689.mount
           404ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1440.mount
           403ms snap-slack-21.mount
           403ms fwupd.service
           402ms accounts-daemon.service
           402ms snap-insomnia-62.mount
           397ms grub-common.service
           391ms systemd-resolved.service
           355ms systemd-logind.service
           247ms nvidia-persistenced.service
           246ms sysstat.service
           244ms keyboard-setup.service
           230ms snap-insomnia-61.mount
           229ms snap-core-8592.mount
           225ms snap-core18-1705.mount
           222ms polkit.service
           219ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-110.mount
           217ms systemd-rfkill.service
           212ms binfmt-support.service
           200ms systemd-sysctl.service
           193ms systemd-modules-load.service
           192ms systemd-udevd.service
           183ms rsyslog.service
           180ms speech-dispatcher.service
           180ms apport.service
           179ms pppd-dns.service
           179ms avahi-daemon.service
           176ms thermald.service
           174ms wpa_supplicant.service
           167ms gpu-manager.service
           167ms lm-sensors.service
           160ms postgresql.service
           144ms dns-clean.service
           141ms console-setup.service
           140ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
           136ms gdm.service
           131ms upower.service
           125ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           118ms systemd-journald.service
            98ms apport-autoreport.service
            98ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            96ms dev-hugepages.mount
            95ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            93ms dev-mqueue.mount
            93ms systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
            91ms colord.service
            76ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
            69ms resolvconf.service
            61ms ufw.service
            60ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            50ms bolt.service
            35ms systemd-random-seed.service
            33ms user@1000.service
            32ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            31ms packagekit.service
            27ms user@128.service
            24ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            16ms snapd.seeded.service
            14ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
            13ms alsa-restore.service
            13ms plymouth-start.service
            11ms plymouth-read-write.service
            10ms kerneloops.service
             5ms dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap
             5ms ureadahead-stop.service
             4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             2ms rtkit-daemon.service
             2ms snapd.socket
             2ms setvtrgb.service
             1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
           753us docker.socket
```

Comment: Add the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze blame` to your question above.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1166486/968501 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1038923/968501

Comment: Normally you would like to use dmesg to inspect kernel issues.  If it says 1min+ in kernel there's no point to do critical-chain and blame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I just realized that this isn't a problem anymore.

```
~ ᐅ  systemd-analyze time  
Startup finished in 3.010s (kernel) + 12.969s (userspace) = 15.979s
graphical.target reached after 12.964s in userspace
```

Currently I'm on this kernal version:

```
~ ᐅ  uname -r
4.15.0-99-generic
```