# Can I improve boot time? dev-sda6.device service takes long

Tags: boot, hard-drive, systemd

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 on an Acer laptop in dual boot with Windows 10. /dev/sda6 is my root partition. Boot takes almost one minute and I don't know if it's normal.
This is the output of systemd-analyze

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.391s (kernel) + 45.645s (userspace) = 53.037s
graphical.target reached after 45.633s in userspace
```

And this is the output of systemd-analyze blame

```
26.767s dev-sda6.device
     24.284s systemd-journal-flush.service
     16.950s systemd-udevd.service
      8.744s systemd-sysctl.service
      7.549s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.793s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.222s mpd.service
      4.040s udisks2.service
      4.018s accounts-daemon.service
      3.775s ModemManager.service
      3.627s NetworkManager.service
      3.410s systemd-modules-load.service
      3.406s snapd.service
      2.778s networkd-dispatcher.service
      2.357s keyboard-setup.service
      1.879s thermald.service
      1.728s apt-daily.service
      1.683s polkit.service
      1.673s grub-common.service
      1.323s gpu-manager.service
      1.178s plymouth-start.service
      1.123s systemd-remount-fs.service
      1.016s dev-mqueue.mount
      1.012s sys-kernel-debug.mount
      1.005s dev-hugepages.mount
       904ms systemd-random-seed.service
       847ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-41222b08\x2d9cb8\x2d4c87\x2d9a05\x2ddaede635edc4.service
       787ms avahi-daemon.service
       780ms ufw.service
       754ms wpa_supplicant.service
       706ms apport.service
       705ms bluetooth.service
       703ms pppd-dns.service                                                                                                                                        
       701ms rsyslog.service
       679ms lm-sensors.service
       669ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-A465\x2d76D5.service
       648ms systemd-logind.service
       488ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       478ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       421ms apparmor.service
       397ms systemd-journald.service
       251ms plymouth-read-write.service
       245ms packagekit.service
       244ms colord.service
       219ms setvtrgb.service
       182ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       182ms upower.service
       165ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       162ms systemd-resolved.service
       113ms user@1000.service
       112ms systemd-rfkill.service
        83ms boot-efi.mount
        76ms plymouth-quit.service
        66ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        64ms rtkit-daemon.service
        62ms snapd.socket
        59ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-613933e2\x2dc62c\x2d4293\x2daf60\x2d73e3507c20cc.swap
        55ms home.mount
        42ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        20ms alsa-restore.service
        20ms snapd.seeded.service
        16ms kerneloops.service
         9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         9ms ureadahead-stop.service
         7ms systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service
         5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         5ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         5ms console-setup.service
         4ms sddm.service
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

I have already solved the problem of apt-daily.service as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service), but there is still a service that takes long, dev-sda6.device. systemd-journal-flush.service also takes quite long.

Is there anything I can do or do I just have a bad hard drive? (the hard drive is new anyway)

Probably `sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=5d` changes something?

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/a/1095784/790920 will improve boot time. I see a lot to improve. Boottime should be ~15s for hdd ( ssd ~ 10s)