# Slow boot of Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I just made a switch from windows to Ubuntu. The only problem is that it takes 4-5, sometimes up to 7 minutes to boot. This is rather annoying.

If there's any more information I can give, please ask.

okay i used the command systemd-analyze
it shows the following in the screenshot
what should i do[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz1WN.png)

Comment: Is that how long a live USB/DVD takes to boot? Or an installed system? Have any peripherals you can unplug for testing

Comment: installed on my PC, i have a TP-LINK wireless USB Adapter, i don't have a duel systems it's only Ubuntu on my PC it's working just fine only this boot issue

Comment: How long did the live USB/DVD take to boot? There are programs that look in log files to see what takes how much time, I don't remember them specifically now, I'd do a web search to find one, was something like "boot time"...

Comment: Two useful commands: `systemd-analyze` & `systemd-analyze blame`. Some more reading: https://www.maketecheasier.com/make-linux-boot-faster/ although you should seek advice here before disabling anything.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service as well. https://askubuntu.com/a/897432/248158 points to a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844453) in which why `systemd` works better on SSDs is mentioned in passing.