# Slow boot after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, upgrade

My system boot-up very slow after the upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 5.731s (firmware) + 4.338s (loader) + 5.616s (kernel) + 1min 25.744s (userspace) = 1min 41.430s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 25.711s in userspace
```

...

```
   systemd-analyze blame
    35.978s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                             >
    24.686s dev-sda6.device                                                        >
    21.190s systemd-journal-flush.service                                          >
    17.983s udisks2.service                                                        >
    15.719s accounts-daemon.service                                                >
    13.912s gpu-manager.service                                                    >
    13.267s NetworkManager.service                                                 >
    12.942s avahi-daemon.service                                                   >
    12.580s polkit.service                                                         >
    12.294s switcheroo-control.service                                             >
    12.285s thermald.service                                                       >
    12.282s wpa_supplicant.service                                                 >
    12.282s systemd-logind.service                                                 >
    10.601s dev-loop3.device                                                       >
    10.456s dev-loop7.device                                                       >
    10.435s dev-loop0.device                                                       >
    10.030s ModemManager.service                                                   >
     9.727s dev-loop4.device                                                       >
     9.282s dev-loop10.device                                                      >
     9.269s dev-loop8.device                                                       >
     9.052s dev-loop5.device                                                       >
     9.040s dev-loop6.device                                                       >
     9.024s dev-loop1.device
```

...

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain  
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 25.711s
└─multi-user.target @1min 25.710s
  └─ModemManager.service @49.195s +10.030s
    └─polkit.service @36.607s +12.580s
      └─basic.target @35.803s
        └─sockets.target @35.803s
          └─uuidd.socket @35.803s
            └─sysinit.target @35.461s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @34.460s +1.000s
                └─apparmor.service @32.093s +2.364s
                  └─local-fs.target @32.092s
                    └─run-user-129-gvfs.mount @1min 11.784s
                      └─run-user-129.mount @1min 9.908s
                        └─swap.target @30.318s
                          └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b54997c\x2d1642\x2d411d\x2d9d0>
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2b54997c\x2d1642\x2d411d\x2d9>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Extremely slow ubuntu 18.04 boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105808/extremely-slow-ubuntu-18-04-boot-time)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance/Boot_process

Basically systemd is a mess so you can improve it but not much

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue.  Fresh install ran fine... was trying to run Clonezilla which was a different issue and pulled the installation media too soon during shutdown.  I was able to rescue the system using boot repair but boot to Ubuntu 20.02 now takes a minute and a half.