# sudo systemctl edit some.service fails because I'm not on a tty

Tags: 20.04, systemd, services, tty

I'm trying to edit the *apt-daily.timer* service because my boot time is very slow. I tried following the top answer on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service). However, when I try running `sudo systemctl edit apt-daily.timer` I keep getting the error ***Cannot edit units if not on a tty.*** Apparently, it shouldn't be an issue in the first place, but I get the same error even when I am on a tty.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, upgraded from 18.04. And my Systemd version is 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround...

I changed from Gnome to Cinnamon and it worked perfectly. Now the service is edited :)